# Permalink issue with News Manager Plugin

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have installed [News Manager Plugin](https://www.dfactory.eu/products/news-manager/) .

I have issue with its permalink. I am using permalink setup as /%category%/%postname%/ in wordpress.

Single news item url is shown as : site.com/news/post-name/

Where as it should be displayed as: site.com/news category name/post-name/

Also I have added news-categories to menu. When news category is clicked instead of other pages url is shown as : site.com/news/category/category-name.
(news and category is static words included in url).

Where as it should reflect as : site.com/news category name/

I have encoded HTML for category news items, where news related to a particular news category will be displayed. But don't know how to link them.

Currently when a news category name is clicked, content of index.php is displayed.

Any help regarding above queries will be appreciated.

In news manager plugin i found following codes for permalink:

```
permalinks' => array(
        'news_slug' => 'news',
        'news_categories_rewrite_slug' => 'category',
        'news_tags_rewrite_slug' => 'tag',
        'single_news_prefix' => false,
        'single_news_prefix_type' => 'category'
    )
```

Does it any way responsible for the permalink issue?

Comment: I am confused, question is not clear to me.

Comment: Question is on using News Manager plugin, single post url is shown as the abc.com/news/sunday-is-funday/. Where as i want abc.com/holiday/sunday-is-funday/. Here holiday is the name of news category and sunday-is-funday is the post title. news is the static word added in url which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your permalink settings by going to your `Admin Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks` and select

```
Custom Structure
```

From available options and paste following code inside that input box which is showing against that radio button which you checked.

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

That will show your URLs in `abc.com/holiday/sunday-is-funday` where holiday is category and `sunday-is-funday` is post type name.

Comment: Already have custom structure with /%category%/%postname%/ in settings but not its showing abc.com/news/sunday-is-funday/ not abc.com/holiday/sunday-is-funday/.

Comment: you have to change  'news_slug' => 'news', this one which what you want ?

Comment: in your case it will be category name so use that one to get category name instead of static 'news' word ...